# Java mail doesn't work in the company's network

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm developing a desktop application that accesses the company's network

Everything is working fine except for the Java Mail library

It works only when I disconnect the device from the company's network and connect it to a regular wifi, but once I connect to the company's network it doesn't send any email.

How can I solve the problem?

The email I'm using for the java mail is Gmail account.

Below is the source code for the mail class:

```
public class Email {

    public void sendEmail(String from, String recipent, String title, String name, String textmsg, String emp_id) throws IOException {

        final String user = "******@gmail.com";
        final String password = "*****";

        String host = "mail.javatpoint.com";
        String to = recipent;

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user, "IT Communication Database"));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(title);
            message.setContent("Below are the assets that were found for the following user: " + emp_id + "\n" + textmsg, "text/html");

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail(String from, String recipent, String title, String name, String textmsg, String search_word) throws IOException {

        final String user = "*****@gmail.com";
        final String password = "*****";

        String host = "mail.javatpoint.com";
        String to = recipent;

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user, "IT Communication Database"));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(title);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're using an smtp server (smtp.gmail.com) that is not accessible from your company network. Either ask your company to make it accessible, or use another smtp server, that is accessible from the network.

Comment: Oh I'll check with them! thank you for your fast reply

Comment: may I ask if there is any other option besides smtp that might work? @JB Nizet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your company's network uses a proxy. If yes, add the below code with the proxy `IP:port details`:

```
properties.setProperty("proxySet","true");
properties.setProperty("socksProxyHost","(proxy IP)");
properties.setProperty("socksProxyPort","(proxy port)");
```

Sample below:

```
properties.setProperty("proxySet","true"); 
properties.setProperty("socksProxyHost","192.168.155.1");
properties.setProperty("socksProxyPort","1080");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i'll ask them about that

Answer (score 0):

Your company blocked port 25 on the firewall to prevent spam.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to deal with this is to use your company's email server instead of Gmail.

If you need to use a proxy server to get outside your company's network, see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).